# how to fix the error "System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'." in net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, docker

I was trying to create two docker images:  asp.net core and postgresq, but connection string doesnt recognize properly the port.

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'


networks:
  -default:
    driver: bridge

services:
  netcoreapi:
    image: netcoreapi:latest
    depends_on:
      - "postgres_image"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
        - default
    environment:
      netcoreapiContext: "host=postgres_image;port=5432;database=gr10_db;username=gr10;password=12345678"

  postgres_image:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "gr10"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "12345678"
      POSTGRES_DB: "gr10_db"
    networks:
       - default

volumes:
  db_volume:
```

and this is my `appsettings.json` :

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "netcoreapiContext": "Server=127.0.0.1; port=5432;Database=gr10_db;Username=gr10;Password=12345678"
  }
```

Nevertheless, when I test the database, it return me the following message:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'. `at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)

if anyone could bring e some help, I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
"netcoreapiContext":"Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=gr10_db;Username=gr10;Password=12345678"
```

Some connection PostgreSQL connection strings examples can be found in [Npgsql docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) or [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/).